# implementing EST server (RFC7030). does github.com/globalsign/est support both client and server properly?

Tags: x509certificate, pki, rfc

We would like to implement a local PKI. I also want to automate the renewal of certificates and the revocation list management. to do so I am considering to use EST protocol. I am thinking of using this repo:
https://github.com/globalsign/est
it has both functionalities of server and client. It seems easy to use and lightweight compared to the other alternatives that I researched. Has anyone used it before? Are there any better recommendation?

I did not try installations yet.